# automate data entry into SharePoint Application Page?

Tags: powershell, automation

i am wondering if there is some scripting language library or technology that exists to be able to automate data entry into a Sharepoint Application Page? The Application Page is just a ASP user interface to a SQL database backend that stores records. i want to be able to automate the entry of these records using the UI. if this question is too vague, then please give me a short explanation as to why... that might help me ask the right question next time.

Comment: See SO Help [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Essentially you are asking for a recommendation for something that is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and too broad for SO.

Comment: Barring that, it's a broad question because I can recommend one way to automate UI entry that I have used with success and is not too difficult is [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com). The whole other end of the spectrum, another, more difficult and complex way, is to directly interface with the SharePoint [REST Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)

Comment: i sincerely appreciate the response.  the REST endpoint sounds like what i was imagining. sounds like the type of skill that will let me automate a bunch of the tedious stuff my team has to do in SharePoint.  i was actually imagining a powershell library that had the ability to write to this kind of gui, but i dont think that exists. and i apologize for the strange question.  i really struggle at thinking through which technologies to use for which problems. once i have a place to start though, i can usually create some good stuff. so thanks again for helping me get started.